# prawn how to move content dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I have a rails project which uses prawn to render pdf, where there is a table printed with many cells inside it, So I have 3 columns in table If the content reaches the end of one column then it should continue in the next one.

```
class OrderPdfNew < Prawn::Document
  def initialize
    cell1 = make_cell(:content => "", size: 4.5)
    ....
    ....
    t = make_table([[cell_1a, cell_1b, cell_1c]...)
    t.draw
  end
end
```

So this is how i need, 
first column has top/bottom, second column top bottom. Start from first column bottom on touching end continue in second column top then bottom last end in first top.

can anyone tell how can this be done?

Comment: maybe split your string in 3 parts (equal length) before you put it in the table?

Comment: @Fallenhero All strings are dynamic so the sizes/length of the string will vary, even if i split how do i find whether content reached the end of table and move the content to next column